# ng-messages is not working on modal

Tags: angularjs

ng-messages is not working on md-dialog. working fine without the modal

```
            <div layout="row">

              <md-input-container flex="50" class="signup-input">
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input  name="firstName" ng-model="user.firstName" required="">
                <div ng-messages="userForm.firstName.$error" md-auto-hide="false">
                  <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                </div>
              </md-input-container>

              <md-input-container flex="50" class="signup-input">
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <input  name="lastName" ng-model="user.lastName" required="">
                <div ng-messages="userForm.lastName.$error">
                  <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                </div>
              </md-input-container>
            </div>
```

[image]

Comment: You should even post controller code as well

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed `angular-message` plugin, if not then do it, check below code.

**Google CDN** : `"//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-messages.js"`

OR

**NPM install** : `npm install angular-messages@X.Y.Z`

OR

**Bower install** : `bower install angular-messages#X.Y.Z`

Then, include `angular-messages.js` in your HTML:
`<script src="path/to/angular.js"></script>`
`<script src="path/to/angular-messages.js"></script>`

Finally, load the module in your application by adding it as a dependent module:
`angular.module('app', ['ngMessages']);`